# Entity Framework shared POCO

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a bit of an issue and I need to know what the best design is for EF.
I have a **Attribute** model:

```
public enum TargetType
{
    Attributes,
    Availability,
    Master
}

public class Attribute
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CriteriaId { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(100)] public string Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)] public string Description { get; set; }
    public TargetType Target { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Formula> Formulas { get; set; }
}
```

It has a list of **Formulas**:

```
public class Formula
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int AttributeId { get; set; }

    [Required] 
    [MaxLength(5)] 
    public string Operator { get; set; }

    [Required] 
    [MaxLength(255)] 
    public string Expression { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)] 
    public string Field { get; set; }
}
```

Which I match up in my `DbContext` like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Attribute>().HasMany(m => m.Formulas).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(m => m.AttributeId);
```

The problem is, I now need to have `Formulas` as a separate property to another class `Answer` like this:

```
public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int QuestionId { get; set; }

    [Required] 
    [MaxLength(255)] 
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public int Order { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Formula> Formulas { get; set; }
}
```

The problem with this is `Formula` has `AttributeId` as a foreign key, so I can't really use the `Formula` model. I would have to create a new one like:

```
public class AnswerFormula
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int AnswerId { get; set; }

    [Required] 
    [MaxLength(5)] 
    public string Operator { get; set; }

    [Required] 
    [MaxLength(255)] 
    public string Expression { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)] 
    public string Field { get; set; }
}
```

But this seems counter-intuitive. So my question is, has anyone come across this before? If so, how did you solve the issue? For me, the problem is further enhanced when I start to use view models and factories.

Comment: Just add another optional foreign key to your `Formula` entity for the relation to `Answer`. Keeping things tidy e.g. have `Formula` only assigned to either `Attribute` or `Answer` would be part of the business logic. Another approach would be to use inheritance on a `BaseFormula` that gets extended by `AnswerFormula` and `AttributeFormula`. The foreignkeys would only be in the inheriting entities.

Comment: If you are going the many-to-many route with AnswerFormula, you don't need to repeat the formula fields - just add 2 navigation properties . One for formula, one for answer. Same thing for AttributeFormula. See [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx).